# Alpha Vantage package installed but not able to find it?

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

Hi I've installed [Alpha Vantage](https://pypi.org/project/alpha-vantage/) I'm getting an error when importing alpha_vantage into my Anaconda project:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18576/239330141.py in <module>
----> 1 from aplha_vantage import TimeSeries

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aplha_vantage'
```

Here's how I've installed it:

```
(base) C:\Users\audac>cd Documents/trading/code

(base) C:\Users\audac\Documents\trading\code>cd stock-scanner-py

(base) C:\Users\audac\Documents\trading\code\stock-scanner-py>cd algorithmic-trading-python

(base) C:\Users\audac\Documents\trading\code\stock-scanner-py\algorithmic-trading-python>pip install alpha_vantage
Requirement already satisfied: alpha_vantage in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from alpha_vantage) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from alpha_vantage) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->alpha_vantage) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->alpha_vantage) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->alpha_vantage) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->alpha_vantage) (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->alpha_vantage) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->alpha_vantage) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->alpha_vantage) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp->alpha_vantage) (3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->alpha_vantage) (1.26.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\audac\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->alpha_vantage) (2021.10.8)

(base) C:\Users\audac\Documents\trading\code\stock-scanner-py\algorithmic-trading-python>
```

I've also tried uninstalling Python and all packages + reinstalling them but I still have the same issue. It only happens with the Alpha Vantage package, everything else works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error:

`aplha_vantage` --> `alpha_vantage`

i.e.

`from alpha_vantage import TimeSeries`